# Is $x^3 + y^3 = z^3$ possible?

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

Is $x^3 + y^3 = z^3$ possible when $x$, $y$ and $z$ are integers? If not, how to prove that they are not possible?

(I am a grade 10 student so please answer in a simple way)

Comment: For *integers*, it is possible quite easily: $y=-x, z=0$. For *positive integers*, you've got special case of [Fermat's Last Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_Last_Theorem) which implies there are no positive solutions.

Comment: $x=y=z=0$ is a solution. $x=1,~ y=-1,~ z=0$ is another.

Comment: http://fermatslasttheorem.blogspot.co.uk/2005/05/fermats-last-theorem-proof-for-n3.html

Comment: To avoid confusion: Fermat's Last Theorem *true* in @PeterKošinár comment means that *no* positive integers can be found that satisfy the equality. So stop searching :-).

Comment: The impossibility of having $x^3+y^3=z^3$ for *positive* integers $x,y,z$ was first proved by Euler in 1770.

Comment: Wikipedia: [Proof of Fermat's Last Theorem for specific exponents](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_of_Fermat%27s_Last_Theorem_for_specific_exponents)

Comment: @BalarkaSen It's interesting from a historic point of view that proofs without Wiles's theorems exist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By [Fermat's Last Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_Last_Theorem) ([Andrew Wiles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrew_Wiles) proved it), if for $x,y,z\in\mathbb Z$
$$x^3+y^3=z^3,$$
then $$xyz=0.$$

This implies that at least one of $x,y,z$ has to be $0$.

So, you'll know there are infinitely many solutions such as $(0,t,t),(t,0,t),(t,-t,0)$ for any $t\in\mathbb Z$.

Comment: I'd like to note that the special case $n=3$ of Fermat's last theorem was proven long before Andrew Wiles (in 1770 by Euler!).

Comment: @Sid: Oh, you are right. Thank you for pointing it out.